# how to set progress bar in file uploading using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

Hi i am uploading multiple files in php so i need to get progress status for uploading files

please any one guide me.

Thanks for Advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a client side uploading component that supports this. [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) and [AJAX upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) are some examples of such controls.

And if you don't want to use a third party control you could implement this functionality yourself. The [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) allows you to do that. There's an example in this article I have linked to. Obviously client browsers need to support the HTML5 File API for this to work.